# Unable to modify ggplot2 x-axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a a dataset such as follows:

```
CON <- data_frame(norm.d.2=c(1.37,1.11,1.84),CDSex.=c(0.439,0.335,0.432))
```

I am plotting this data frame with ggplot2, but I am unable to change the x axis labels. I have tried both scale_x_continuous and scale_x_discrete, but either I receive an error or no labels at all.
[image: default plot]

```r
ggplot(CONrc,aes(x=norm.d.2,y=CDSex.)) + 
   geom_point(aes(color=factor(interaction(hpi,rep)))) +
   xlab('Exonic % of Cellular Reads') +
   ylab('CDS % of Exonic Reads')
```

When I try `scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0.5,1.5,2.5))`, I get the following error:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

When I try `scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(0.5,1.5,2.5))`, I do not get an error message, but my plot loses all x axis labels.

[image: ggplot2 using scale_x_discrete]

Answer (score 1):

looks fine for `CON` table.

try to mutate `CONrc`

```
CONrc$norm.d.2 <- as.double(CONrc$norm.d.2)
```

and then plot this